# Can I create an Active Record relationship based on no matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I’m trying to speed up an index page on a rails application which has a lot of n+1 queries.

At the moment I have a method which basically reverses a relationship (finds the records not related to the current one)

```rb
Class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to_many :bankholidays, join_table: “working_bankholidays”

    def free_bankholidays
        Bankholiday.where(“id NOT IN (?)” bankholiday_ids)
    end
end
```

```rb
Class Bankholiday < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to_many :persons, join_table: “working_bankholidays”
end
```

```rb
Class WorkingBankholiday < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :bankholiday
end
```

The free_bankholidays method inside Person returns any Bankholidays which aren't related to the current Person. This works fine but slows things down if I'm loading an index page with multiple persons. Is there a way I can move this out to a relationship so it can be eager loaded?

Comment: This is called an outer join. It's a standard part of SQL syntax, and activerecord provides a method to construct such queries.

Comment: I am not certain you will be able to eager load something that is not associated in anyway.  You can certainly query this data by using a more complex join condition but there is no railsy way that I know of to join this back to the original user for eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an out join, and select the results where the outer join created NULLs.

The SQL you will want is:

```
SELECT bankholidays.*
FROM bankholidays
  LEFT OUTER JOIN working_bankholidays on bankholidays.id = working_bankholidays.bankholiday_id
  AND working_bankholidays.person_id = 111
WHERE working_bankholidays.id is NULL
```

The problem here is that you need the condition for the `person_id` in the **`FROM`** clause.  If it is in the `WHERE` clause you will get different results.

When it is in the FROM clause, it will use the condition to treat the `working_bankholidays` table as if it only had the rows with the matching `person_id`.  It does this before doing the outer join, so if there are no records with the matching `person_id` it will add records from the outer join, with NULL values in all the fields for the `working_bankholidays` table.

Unfortunately, I do not know any way to do this with active record associations.  All active record associations put conditions into the `WHERE` clause, and not the `FROM` clause.

If you change the `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` to has many through, and you do this:

```
class Person
  def free_bankholidays
    Bankholiday.left_joins(:working_bankholidays).where(working_bankholidays: {id: nil, person_id: self.id})
  end
```

it will give you this:

```
SELECT bankholidays.*
FROM bankholidays
  JOIN working_bankholidays on bankholidays.id = working_bankholidays.bankholiday_id
WHERE working_bankholidays.id is NULL
  AND working_bankholidays.person_id = 111
```

which will give you different and incorrect results.

EDIT:

See comment by engineersmnky.  I have not tried that yet, so I am not ready to include it in my answer.

Comment: `arel` can do this for you. `joins(WorkingBankholiday.arel_table.join(Bankholiday.arel_table,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(WorkingBankholiday.arel_table[:bankholiday_id].eq(Bankholiday.arel_table[:id]).and(WorkingBankholiday.arel_table[:person_id].eq(111))).join_sources)`